# Is it possible to add a web user control to a class library in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was trying to add Web user control in Class Library in VS2010.

is there a way to do that?

Comment: not sure but I think that you can inherit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at last I found one way, 
just copy the files from other project (website/ web application) and pest them inside Class Library Project.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. I was trying to add web user control to class library project and your post helped me.