# Web User Control Library in VS2010 & .net 4?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0, class-library, web-user-controls

**Is it possible to somehow load Web User Controls from another project / class library using Visual Atudio 2010 and ASP.NET 4.0?**

I only found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295586/is-it-possible-to-add-a-web-user-control-to-a-class-library-in-vs2010) (all the other are for VS2008 & ASP.NET 2.0 or older), but that doesn't work for me:
I can reference the control and compile when its copied to the class library project, but nothing is rendered to the page.

Is there (an easy way) to achive that so that it can be used in daly business?

The main goal is to have reusable controls which we can use in several web applications we are developing in paralell.